# How to use cut for showing the first field of a file

Tags: linux, bash

Below is my data file sname , I use command `cut -f1 sname` to output Number in that file. But it outputs Name field at the same time.

```
11  Vivek
12  Renuka
13  Prakash
```

Separator is `tab`.

**EDIT:** As @fancyPants points out, I find in my .vimrc `set tabstop=8`
. That's the problem. **`cut -f1 sname` works.**

Comment: @anubhava Shell outputs: `cut: the delimiter must be a single character`

Comment: The normal delimiter for cut is tab, you obviously do not have tabs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The default separator for `cut` is a space, not tabulator.</s>

You can specify it either by pressing `CTRL-v Tab`

```
cut -f1 -d'   ' sname
```

or this way:

```
cut -f1 -d$'\t' sname
```

Correction: The default delimiter for cut is tab, so this is not necessary.

Edit: When this doesn't work, you don't have tabs there. You can check for tabs when you look at the file with vi. Then you enter these commands:

```
:set list
```

for a tab you should see `^I` or to make it more clear you can use

```
:set listchars=tab:>-
```

Then the tabs will show as `>---`.

EDIT 2:

I think your problem is, that you have multiple whitespaces. When you don't want to use awk, which is surely easier, this would be an alternative:

```
sed 's/ \+/ /g' sname | cut -f2 -d" "
```

sed replaces multiple whitespaces with one.

Comment: @hel I edited my answer so you can check if you actually have tabs in your file.

Comment: The default delimiter for cut is tab.

Comment: @fancyPants It doesn't show `tab`, just `$` in the end of line. But I type `tab` in my data file.

Comment: @hel Then you probably have multiple whitespaces instead. Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @fancyPants Indeed, really, it's `tab`.

Comment: @123 Oops, you're right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @hel What makes you think so? When neither `vi` nor `cat -vte` show a tab, then you don't have tabs.

Comment: @fancyPants Really, I create a new file and type `tab`, `:set list` just show `$` in the end of line. OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Pressing a tab doesn't mean tab is inserted. Based on .vimrc it can convert tab to multiple spaces as well

Comment: @anubhava  Thanks!

Comment: or just `sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' sname`

Answer (score 3):

try awk;

```
awk '{print $1}' sname
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to modify `cut` to make it work?